# multiple selectors for jquery on

Tags: jquery

I need two conditions to be true for my selector.  I would like the listener to hear events for the below buttons.  My current selector doesn't work:

html:

```
        <div class="myclass" data="mydata">
          <button>1</button>
          <button>2</button>
          <button>3</button>
        </div>
```

javascript(does not work):

```
    $('body').on('click.myListener', '[data^=mydata] .myclass > button  ', function (e) {})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the space between the `attribute` and `class` selectors:

```
$('body').on('click.myListener', 'div[data^=mydata].myclass > button', function (e) {})
```